# Display status of a running process in PeopleSoft

Tags: sql, peoplesoft, peoplecode

So I have a button in a page wherein when it is pressed, it kicks off a process, specifically an application engine. As we all know, when an app engine runs, it is being shown in the process monitor page.

What I want to do is on that same page that I have, the status of the application can be displayed or seen. That part of the page should look like this (see photo [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErFUn.png)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetch the runstatus of your process from the table PSPRCSRQST.

The runstatus is an XLAT value. See the table PSXLATITEM where fieldname='RUNSTATUS' for the description of the runstatus